# How to get a parameter from the url with JS?

Tags: html, .htaccess, routes

I am creating friendly urls, I have a js code where I obtain the parameter to send it to another file with that data:

this is the code:

```
function recorrerListaInsertCursos(){
  //alert('Entro a recorrerListaInsertCursos');
var listaChecksAddCursos = '';
$("input[name=checkbox2]").each(function (index) {  
   if($(this).is(':checked')){
      listaChecksAddCursos +=$(this).val()+',';
      //$("#valoresChecks").val(listaChecks); 
      valoresChecksAddCursos = '';
      valoresChecksAddCursos = listaChecksAddCursos;
      val_usu = '';
      val_usu = getUrlParameter('id_u');
      console.log(val_usu);
      alert(location.href="../insertCoursesUser/" + valoresChecksAddCursos + "&" + val_usu);
   }
});
return listaChecks;

}
```

I print the variable val_usu in the console and it says that it is not defined.
The url I have is this:

http://localhost:82/admonCapacitacion/cursos/cursosUsuario/27

My file .htaccess I have this:

```
    Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Activar RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /admonCapacitacion/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^admonCapacitacion/c/css.*$
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RedirectMatch ^/(.*?)/$ /$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^cursos/cursosUsuario/(.+)\.php cursos/cursosUsuario.php?id_u=$1
Rewriterule ^cursos/insertCoursesUser/(.+),&(.+) cursos/insertCoursesUser.php?idsAddCourse=$1&id_u=$2

</IfModule>
```

Please someone give me an idea on how to solve this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
function getParam(url) {
if (url = (new RegExp('[?&]' + encodeURIComponent(url) + '=([^&]*)')).exec(location.search))
    return decodeURIComponent(url[1]);
}
```

Usage:
let myparam = getParam("id_u");